# How to get form result URL jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, url, action

HTML

```
<form action="/" method="get" class="form-search" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="search" name="s" id="search" placeholder="Search" value="test">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />
</form>
```

result: `/?s=test&post_type=post`

JS

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formAction = $(this).attr("action");
  alert(formAction);
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/" method="get" class="form-search" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="search" name="s" id="search" placeholder="Search" value="test">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />
</form>

result<br> <strong>/?s=test&post_type=post</strong>
```

Result: `/`

Comment: There's no question here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.serialize()` to get all the form inputs as a URL-encoded string.

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formAction = $(this).attr("action");
  const formFields = $(this).serialize();
  alert(`${formAction}?${formFields}`);
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/" method="get" class="form-search" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="search" name="s" id="search" placeholder="Search" value="test">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />
</form>

result<br> <strong>/?s=test&post_type=post</strong>
```